# is there a way to turn off the edge screen on the Samsung Galaxy Note Edge?

Tags: samsung

I don't think the edge screen is useful.

Often, its just causing unexpected things to trigger and run.

Can it be turned off?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you can't turn it off.But you can set timeout for it as low as possible to turn it offf quickly.
Settings > Edge Screen > Edge Screen Timeout

Comment: I don't see an option for Edge Screen Timeout. The only items are: manage panels, express me, information stream, night clock, and personal message.

Comment: Check in information stream it is avalable there

Comment: All that I have there (in Information stream) is Yahoo Finance, News, Sports.

Answer (score -1):

You can't exactly turn it off but b you can turn off all the edge screen features individually if you no longer need them